# Puppteer fails to use Firefox

Tags: node.js, firefox, puppeteer

I'd like to use Firefox as a browser for my scraping app. I'm calling it like

```
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
         product: 'firefox',
         headless: true,
         args: ["--no-sandbox"]
      });
```

...and the scraping attempt returns:

```
Error: Could not find expected browser (firefox) locally. Run `PUPPETEER_PRODUCT=firefox npm install` to download a supported Firefox browser binary
```

NB:
This is not the deprecated `puppeteer-firefox` thing, I'm talking about the Firefox natively supported by Puppeteer.

What I've tried so far:

- running the suggested command locally (package-lock.json was updated, package.json stayed the same)
- removing Puppeteer folder from `node_modules` and running `npm install` to refresh it
- made sure that Puppeteer version is 10.2.0, newest so far
- made sure that I've got the 14th version of node (at first installer returned an error that he needs 14th node specifically)
- npm is also the latest one

Can someone whose Firefox for Puppeteer works fine please check their package-lock.json and maybe package.json too, and share the parts of these files which are related to Puppteer? Or share thoughts how can I make it work? Where is the Firefox support declared anyway?

PS: I'm not running my app locally, I deploy it straight to Heroku and launch there.

Answer (score 2):

To resolve this I did the following:

- Run `npm config set puppeteer_product=firefox`
- Then run `npm install puppeteer`

Reference:
https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/7044

Answer (score 0):

Actually the command in error is not complete. You can run this
`PUPPETEER_PRODUCT=firefox npm i puppeteer`